# How to erase duplicated element in row of a list in python

Tags: python, list

I don't know exactly how to explain this for the title, so here some code to express what I need. I have a list like this:

```
lst = [['24', 'john', 'july, 'email@gmail.com],
       ['12', 'alice', 'auguts, 'email@hotmail.com],
       ['48', 'john', 'september, 'email@outlook.com],
       [ ....]]
```

I want to erase all duplicated sublists with the same name (name being the second field in each sublist), in this case I want the final list to be:

```
lst = [['24', 'john', 'july, 'email@gmail.com],
       ['12', 'alice', 'auguts, 'email@hotmail.com]
       [ ....]]
```

I don't want to find a duplicated list and erase it, I want to erase a list which has a duplicated field. Sorry if I didn't explain myself well.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think what you need is a dictionary not a list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set` to check duplicates.

```
>>> lst = [
...     ['24', 'john', 'july', 'email@gmail.com'],
...     ['12', 'alice', 'auguts', 'email@hotmail.com'],
...     ['48', 'john', 'september', 'email@outlook.com'],
... ]
>>> 
>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for item in lst:
...     name = item[1]
...     if name not in seen:
...         seen.add(name)
...         result.append(item)
... 
>>> result
[['24', 'john', 'july', 'email@gmail.com'],
 ['12', 'alice', 'auguts', 'email@hotmail.com']]
```

Don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#typesseq).

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> [x for x in lst if (x[1] not in seen, seen.add(x[1]))[0]]
[['24', 'john', 'july', 'email@gmail.com'],
 ['12', 'alice', 'auguts', 'email@hotmail.com']]
```

Comment: Just the perfect answer falsetru. I had seen set in other scripts but never stopped to study them. Thank's for both codes!

Answer (score 1):

Using filter:

```
lst = [['24', 'john', 'july', 'email@gmail.com'],
       ['12', 'alice', 'auguts', 'email@hotmail.com'],
       ['48', 'john', 'september', 'email@outlook.com']
       ]
seen = {}
def filter_condition(item):
    if item[1] in seen: return False
    seen[item[1]] = 1 
    return True

print filter(filter_condition, lst)
```

Comment: You don't need the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive approach, renaming your starting list to `oldlist` to avoid a naming problem with the builtin Python `list`.

```
newlist = []
for j, sublist in enumerate(oldlist):
  unique = True
  for laterlist in oldlist[j+1:]:
    if any([sublist[k] == laterlist[k] for k in range(len(sublist))]):
      unique = False
  if unique:
    newlist.append(sublist)
```